# Insert a number to the random position in an array of random number

Tags: java, android, arraylist, random

I'm developing a simple game to add 2 number and select a result in a gridview. But I've only put a number to 1st or last position of my list's Array. How to add my result to the random position without give it an exactly index? 
Here is my code:

```
x=random.nextInt(11);
a=a+x;
for (int j=1;j<25;){
    int random=((int)(Math.random()*25))+1;
    if (!list.contains(random)){
        list.add (a+random);
        j++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply adds your random numbers in your list as you do then call [Collections.shuffle(List)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle(java.util.List)) to reorder your List randomly.

Answer (score 0):

1. First create array with N Values (Blank/Null we can say)
2. Now you need to generate random number between 0 to N-1
3. Use above value as index and store you value.

Answer (score 0):

```
private List <Integer> createRandomIndexes() {
    List<Integer> indexes = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 1; i < 25; i++) {
        indexes.add(i);
    }
    Collections.shuffle(indexes);
    return indexes;
}
```

Here's the key to random

```
Collections.shuffle(indexes);
```